# How to store a segues as a variable and still use it?

Tags: swift

```
var realAddress1 : CLLocationDegrees = 0.0
var realAddress2 : CLLocationDegrees = 0.0
var cooksLocation = CooksLocation()
let hello : [String] = []

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) -> CLLocationDegrees  {
    let cooksLocation = segue.destination as! CooksLocation
    cooksLocation.address1 = realAddress1

    return realAddress1
}
```

Here is a sample of my code. The problem is that it does not return the new value for the var `realAdress1`.

Comment: Between your title and question, I'm having a hard time understanding the "specific" issue. (And absolutely, it's likely a language issue.) (1) You *can't* store a *segue* as a variable. AFAIK it's something you can only create in IB. (2) But your code appears to be looking to do something very different. It doesn't `override` anything a segue does and is doing something (but I don't know what) with `realAddress1`. Could you elaborate with the specifics on that? Are you trying to pass it from one view controller to the net?

Comment: The standard `UIViewController prepare(for:sender:)` method can't have a return value.

Comment: First, when you custom the original

    `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`
to your 

    `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) -> CLLocationDegrees `

it will not call your custom function automatically. Be careful

Second, I don't see your `realAddress1` setter in your custom function. You did not set new value for your `realAddress1`

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the above code will always return a value of 0.0

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) -> CLLocationDegrees  {
```

is not the signature of a method that will ever be called automatically. The correct signature is

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
```

which does not return a value. If you want to store a value in response to this method being called, store it in an instance property, or call some method and pass it.

Comment: well, then I how do I return the new value of the var realAddress1

Comment: You don’t return it. It’s an instance property. You can get it and set it from anywhere.

Comment: Then how do i get it

Comment: You say `realAddress1`, just as you are doing in your code. It seems to me that part of the problem here is that you don't even know what your code does.

Comment: In my code, there is an error that keeps showing up.

Comment: Uh-huh. But your question said nothing about that. If that's what the question was supposed to be about, then the question should have mentioned that fact (in detail).